# Unable to load class, to missing dependency

Tags: grails

I need to upload file:

```
def newTeam(String nameTeam){
render '123 ' + nameTeam
if(request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest) {
MultipartHttpServletRequest mpr = (MultipartHttpServletRequest)request
CommonsMultipartFile f = (CommonsMultipartFile) mpr.getFile("myFile");
}
}
```

i have error:

> 2017-04-11 23:22:37.416 ERROR --- [      Thread-12]
>   grails.boot.GrailsApp                    : Compilation Error: startup
>   failed: General error during class generation:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile due to
>   missing dependency Lorg/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem;
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to
>   load class
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile due to
>   missing dependency Lorg/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem; at
>   more....

[It is fix.](https://brainflush.wordpress.com/2008/12/04/how-to-gracefully-recover-from-file-upload-errors-in-grails/) But i do not know how to use it. I have to write the dsl code in my resources.groovy.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the following to build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    compile 'commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.2'
}
```