# Grails 3 upload file limit size

Tags: grails, file-upload, grails-controller, grails-3.3, grails-config

---

**What i am doing and what happened?**

---

I am trying to **upload files in grails** and dowloand them. After make it, I am still facing a problem, **when the file size is large**. Here is the exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: 
the request was rejected because its size (3553808) exceeds the configured maximum (128000)
```

---

**What I tryed and the result:**

---

I found this asked before in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845943/grails3-file-upload-maxfilesize-limit), and the answer is to put some **configuration variables**:

```
grails:
    controllers:
        upload:
            maxFileSize: (10 * 1024 * 1024)
            maxRequestSize: (10 * 1024 * 1024)
```

**But still getting the same error**. I also tryed to add some dependencies as [said here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356186/unable-to-load-class-to-missing-dependency). Or close IDE And rebuild. And nothing could be solved.

---

**Did someone face this issue and could solved it?**

Comment: Did you try any of the other answers on the linked question, like [this bean configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29857024/487033)?

Comment: I tried it, but couldn't solve imports

Comment: I tried it again in combination with `compile group: 'commons-fileupload', name: 'commons-fileupload', version: '1.3.3'`. This solved the problem, but can't find the file in the request as before.

Comment: The answer with the bean configuration also said that there is no need of any dependencies or additional configuration.

Comment: Is your deployment container enforcing this limit perhaps?  How are you running/deploying your application?

Comment: I am running it in the IntelliJ IDEA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the assignation of the cofig variables. I assign them without operators:

```
        maxFileSize: 10485760
        maxRequestSize: 10485760
```

Instead of:

```
        maxFileSize: (10 * 1024 * 1024)
        maxRequestSize: (10 * 1024 * 1024)
```

This is how I solved the problem.

Comment: were you able to catch the FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException if the upload size is bigger than the one configured?

Comment: Sorry! I don't remember the behaviour of that, more that 2 years without touching that temary :S

Answer (score 0):

Following working fine for me with grails version 3.2 and above

We are going to allow 25MB files uploads.

25 * 1024 * 1024 = 26.214.400 bytes

**My `/grails-app/conf/application.yml`**

```
grails:
 controllers:
  upload:
    maxFileSize: 26214400
    maxRequestSize: 26214400
```

**My `my.gsp` file**

```
<g:form action="saveImage" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

    <input type="file" placeholder="Select file" name="file">

    <g:submitButton value="Upload File"/>

</g:form>
```

**My `controller` action**

```
def saveImage(){
def fileName = ''
def uploadedFile = request.getFile('file')

if (uploadedFile)
    if (!uploadedFile.empty) {
        try {

            int dot = uploadedFile.originalFilename.lastIndexOf('.');
            def fileExt = uploadedFile.originalFilename.substring(dot + 1);
            fileName = ("myFile." + fileExt).toString()
            def basePath = ''
            if (Environment.current == Environment.PRODUCTION) {
                basePath ='/var/local/prj/uploads/' // this works with production and tested on Ubuntu OS
            } else {
                basePath = grailsApplication.mainContext.servletContext.getRealPath('/uploads/') // this will take your project directory path Project\src\main\webapp\uploads folder
            }
            uploadedFile.transferTo(new File(basePath + fileName))
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    // Your redirect code here
}
```

**Download file action**

```
def file = new File("Your file path")
if (file.exists()) {
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream") // or or image/JPEG or text/xml or whatever type the file is
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"${file.name}\"")
    response.outputStream << file.bytes
} else 
    render "File does not exist!"
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Note: Working with IntelliJ IDEA 2016/2017/2018 :)

Comment: @IgniteCoders what is the size of file, which you are trying to upload?

Comment: I am trying to upload different size files. between 10 and 2 Mb. But i solved it finally, look at my answer.

Comment: I think i also mentioned same :) check `maxFileSize: 26214400 and maxRequestSize: 26214400`

Comment: Yea, but i never thought that could be the problem. Because i didnt get any error, the config just take default and skiping the mine.

Comment: and how to deal with exceptions if file is bigger than the limit?

Comment: @PabloPazos 

Grails default size for file uploads is 128000 (~128KB). When this limit is exceeded you’ll see the exception:

`org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException`

Comment: yep, but that exception AFAIK is thrown before the controller, so where to do the catch?